# SQL to retrieve Oracle Function Parameters

Tags: oracle, function, data-dictionary

Is there any way to pull from the data dictionary the parameters for a particular function?  I've seen some query tools display this information and I'm wondering if they are parsing the DDL or if Oracle stores this information somewhere.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  [`dba_|all_|user_arguments`](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:409975400346767486) will have that information.  For a function, the argument at `position` 0 will be the return value.